# Proving continuity of a map between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, continuity

I am trying to $\text {show that } f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \text { given by } f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{x_1 x_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}} & \text { if } x \neq 0 \\
0 & \text { if } x=0
\end{array}\right\} \text { is continuous at } 0$.

Is the following correct?

Consider arbitrary $\epsilon>0$. Consider arbitrary $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Set $\delta:=\epsilon.$ Suppose $x\neq0$ (the case that $x=0$ is trivial).

Suppose that $x_{1} \neq 0, x_2 \neq0$. Then, $d(x,0)=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}<\delta \implies \sqrt{x_2^2}=|x_2|<\epsilon \implies d(f(x), f(0))=\big|\frac{x_1 x_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}\big|\leq \big|\frac{x_1 x_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2}}\big|=\frac{|x_1||x_2|}{|x_1|}=|x_2|<\epsilon$.

Suppose next that one of $x_1, x_2$ is zero. WLOG, suppose that $x_1=0$. Then, $d(x,0)=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}<\delta \implies  d(f(x), f(0))=\big|\frac{x_1 x_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}\big|=0<\epsilon$.

Comment: Some more care is needed above, you need to address the possibility that $x_1 = 0$.

Comment: No, that’s not a good argument because $x_1$ might be $0$. The shorter, and sufficient, bound is $\frac{|x_1|}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}\leq 1$.

Comment: @copper.hat Does my edit provide an adequate treatment of that possibility?

Comment: Yes. Also, you just need to deal with $x_1 \ne 0$ and $x_1 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

As commenters have pointed out, this argument is not valid in the case when $x_1=0$, which could certainly happen. An alternative way to do it would be to notice that

$$0\leq\frac{\lvert x_1\lvert\rvert x_2\rvert}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2}\sqrt{x_2^2}}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}\leq\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}.$$

Now just let $(x_1,x_2)\to(0,0)$ to get the result.